# draw ios quartz 2d path with a varying alpha component

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, bezier

I'd like to paint some Bezier curves with the alpha channel that is changing during the curve painting. Right now I'm able to draw bezier paths, with a fixed alpha channel. What I'd like to do is to draw a single bezier curve that uses a certain value of the alpha channel for the first n points of the path another, alpha value for the subsequent m points and so on.
The code I'm using for drawing bezier path is:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, curva.color.CGColor);
....
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
....
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm describing?

Many thanks,
Giovanni

Comment: Stroke color is a context setting, so you cannot change it while you're drawing a path. So it is better you split the path in many sub-paths on each alpha change and then stroke them separately; so: - set alpha0; - stroke subpath0; - set alpha1; - stroke subpath1; - set alpha2; stroke subpath2; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I imagine you could achieve this effect:

- If you absolutely must compute the alpha at draw time, you could experiment with creating a colored CGPatternRef ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPattern/Reference/reference.html ) whose drawing callback inspects the current context translation and draws a color based on the offset. Instead of setting a stroke color, you'd set CGContextSetStrokePattern to your created pattern.
- If appropriate for the drawn object, you could precompute the alpha across the space of the curve and use your CGPathRef as a mask for the alpha image.

I should qualify that I've never attempted the CGPatternRef method, so I can only point that out as a potential, not a certainty.

Comment: I understand how to proceed with option one, but I don't know how to go on with option two (GCPathRef as a mask for the image) Can you elaborate a little more the second solution?

Comment: Absolutely.  The second solution would involve creating an in-memory image that represented the color change of your alpha across the space of the drawn path.  You would do this using CGBitmapContextCreate() to create the image, and then likely creating a CGGradientRef and filling the bitmap context with that gradient.  Once you have this in memory image, you would add the path you created to the graphics context with CGContextAddPath, then clip the next drawing operation with CGContextClip.  Now that you're clipping with that path draw the in memory image to the screen with CGContextDrawImage

Comment: That in-memory image mentioned above could also be drawn across the course of the path by creating a CGColor instance from the image - [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:aUIImageObtainedFromTheInMemoryImage] - and then setting the stroke color of the path to the CGColor of the UIColor returned, and simply draw-stroking the path.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the second solution but I'm not getting the result. What gets painted is all the rectangle containing the curve, it paints the gradient as a background and the bezier curve. The curve is an open path; perhaps the CGContextClip does work only on closed path? I'm new to stackoverflow I don't know if I must ask a new question with the code I developed or edit the original one in order to see what I'm doing.

Comment: The above link has code for doing technique 2, which will probably yield undesirable results if you don't have a closed path.  There's also a working example for what you are intending to do (open path), which involves drawing the path to an image mask bitmap, and using that mask bitmap to mask a gradient fill on the main context.

Comment: you rock! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do what you are trying to do:

1. Create a gradient image using your favorite graphics editor (or create it just in time in your app). The image should be 1 pixel tall and as wide as the length of the path you are going to stroke.
2. Fill the image with your gradient. For example, fill the image with a gradient that has a varying alpha component from 0 on the left to 1 on the right.
3. Create your stroke color by calling [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage] where the pattern image is a UIImage created from the gradient image.
4. Use the pattern color to stroke your path. This also works with layers. This will apply the gradient along the path.